# Не отрабатывает программа при загрузке и выключении Windows

Tags: windows, delphi

Добрый день! Написал программу, которая должна выполняться при загрузке и выключении Windows (при выключении программе передается параметр). Поставил в gpedit.msc - Конфигурация компьютера - Конфигурация Windows - Сценарии соответственно user_in.cmd:

```
S:  
cd S:\SoftGO\Soft\RUN\Tabel\    
InOut.exe
```

и user_out.cmd:

```
S:  
cd S:\SoftGO\Soft\RUN\Tabel\    
InOut.exe 1
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Exception EOleException in module InOut.exe at 0009C52B. Пользователю
"GO/PROG$" не удалось войти в
систему.
```

Где может быть ошибка?
 Вот программа InOut:

```
program InOut;

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, DB, ADODB, Grids, DBGrids, ExtCtrls, ActiveX;

var ADO: TADOCommand;
    StrInOut: AnsiString;

  function GetComputer: AnsiString;  
    var   dwI: DWord;  
    begin  
      dwI:= MAX_PATH;  
      SetLength(Result,MAX_PATH+1);  
      if GetComputerName(PChar(Result),dwI) then  
        SetLength(Result,dwI)  
      else SetLength(Result,0);  
    end;

begin  
  { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }  
  try  
    CoInitialize(nil);  
    if ParamCount()=0 then  
      StrInOut:= '[ТабельВход]'  
    else  
      StrInOut:= '[ТабельВыход]';  
    ADO:= TADOCommand.Create(nil);  
    with ADO do begin  
      ConnectionString:='Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;'+  
        'Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=dbReostat;'+  
        'Data Source=FILESERVER';  
      CommandText:= 'EXEC ' + StrInOut + ' ' + QuotedStr(GetComputer());  
      Execute();  
    end;  
  finally  
    ADO.Free();  
    CoUninitialize;  
  end;  
end.
```

Comment: Не стесняемся пользоваться кнопкой `101010`, когда постим кусок кода.

Comment: А пользователь Windows с именем `GO/PROG$`, под которым вы пытаетесь зайти, имеет полномочия на SQL-сервере?

Comment: Не знаю. Видимо надо использовать SQL-аутентификацию вместо windows- аутентификации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, СУБД еще не успела подняться.
Проверьте просто работу программы, а не во время запуска.